# Android Kotlin Two-Way databinding BR class error

Tags: kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I'am trying to do a basic android application using kotlin and  two way data binding to show  on a text view the changes in a edit text. But i'am getting this error :
 **w: [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding (DYNAMIC).**

when i'am trying to do with one way data binding it is working well it show me the Contact class's name field successful

my codes:
build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mvvm.demo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**my Contact.kt**

```
    import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable
    import androidx.databinding.Bindable

    class Contact( var Id:Int,
                   var Name:String,
                   var Email:String):BaseObservable() {

        @Bindable
        var _name: String = Name
            set(value) {
                field = value
                notifyPropertyChanged(BR._name)
            }
            get() = field
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately, this error has not yet been resolved. I hope the warning will be resolved in the next update. I've been waiting for updates since November because of this warning

source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110061530#comment28

Comment: The only way is after adding @Bindable notation rebuild your project and so go on.

Comment: There are more than 1000 classes in my project and I do it a bit grueling :) Do you know a different method?

Comment: I do not know any other solution for this situation. We will wait the new version of android studio i think :)